# Doing simple math in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have variable `$page` in my PHP page and in a query I want to use this like:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT (3*($page-1)),3");
//right here I want to this math but it gives me error.
```

I tried it in that way too

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT (3*{$page-1}),3");
```

It gave me that message:

**syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '}'**

How should do this math in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your problem is not one of SQL, but of how PHP interpolates strings.

Your problem is that PHP will interpolate variables into strings, but not expressions.

You can do this as suggested above:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT " . (3*($page-1)) . ",3");
```

Or you could do this:

```
$limit = 3*($page-1);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT $limit,3");
```

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT " . (3*($page-1)) . ",3"); dosent work. $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT $limit,3"); works great. WTF?

Comment: I don't know what "doesn't work" means.  I also don't respond well to "WTF".

Comment: WTF always using on internet it doesn't mean somebody says bad thingsto you.and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third LIMIT " . (3*($page-1)) . ",3");
```

Just calculate the value in `PHP` and concatenate :)

Comment: Concat operator is `.` :)

Comment: @scrowler Right you are, working with java all day :)

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? Do you have an error or something alike?